Add a leading 0 when input value is .00 using react-imask
How can I add a leading 0 when the input value is .00. For example I will enter a value of .99 and it will automatically append 0.99 and if I enter a whole number it will append .00, for example I will enter 50 then i will automatically append 50.00.
I tried mask="00.00" but this will accept only 2 digits number.
